# Postcode data from SQL Server populating google map using jscript, C# and bcp commands

Tags: c#, sql-server, google-maps, jscript, bcp

I have a SQL Server database which contains customer records and most importantly postcodes which I want to be displayed on a map.

Exploring this forum I found a good article which describes how multiple postcodes can be sent through a google maps API and then displayed on my own webpage. This is the article: '[Adding multiple pins to Google Maps by UK post code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638725/adding-multiple-pins-to-google-maps-by-uk-post-code)'.

This doesn't serve my purpose because I want my postcodes from a specific SQL query injected into the jscript rather than having to manually type the postcodes into the code. The area I'm talking about is shown in the extract from original code below:

```
var postcodes = [
      'SL59JH',
      'LU13TQ',
      'SR29TD',
      'DA75BQ',
      'EC1V9B'
    ];
```

So far I have come up with this solution to get the desired postcode data out of SQL and output it to a text file using a bcp command:

```
bcp "SELECT CHAR(39) + Clients_Postcode + CHAR(39) + ',' FROM Clients WHERE Clients_Type = 'retail' OR Clients_Type = 'hospitality'" queryout C:\postcodes.txt -c -S server01 -d AllClients -T
```

Notice the formatting I've achieved in the resultant text file: the SQL select statement puts the apostrophe and comma characters into the data in an attempt to match the format of the postcodes given in the original code taken from the aforementioned article.

Now, I want the contents of the text file to be used in the jscript highlighted above so that the google map generated will show all the postcodes pulled from the text file generated by the bcp command.

This is how I imagine the markup but don't know if it is possible to achieve what I want, neither do I know the required syntax.

```
var postcodes = [
              ' ' //postcodes from text file
            ];
```

I am a beginner and would really appreciate help from people of greater experience/ability than myself; thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a way that satisfies my needs. I would have preferred not to have used PHP but it seems the only way was to use the "file_get_contents()" PHP command.

Obviously I had to rename the web page file extension *.php and had to install PHP support into IIS, but here is the working bit of code I was asking for, albeit not a JScript or C# version that I had desired but it seems there isn't one without over-complicating things:

```
var postcodes = [<?php $data1 = file_get_contents("postcodes.txt"); {echo $data1;} ?>];
```

The postcodes listed in the text file were then effectively placed on a google map. Unfortunately, the free Google Maps API only allows up to 8 beacons at a time to be shown on the map.